# Eclipse Arduino Leonardo Pro Micro ATMega32U4 Programming Issue

Tags: atmega32u4

Help Needed as I am little bit lost. I've procured a Pro Micro Board from sparkfun. Great little board and it work like clock work when using the standard Arduino Programming IDE.

Well Copied the code thru to the Eclipse Project, Hit compile and all seems well. But Trying to write the code to the device the following happens.

---

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

```
     System wide configuration file is "C:/Users/vente/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino14/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM5
     Using Programmer              : avr109
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
     AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
     Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
     PAGEL                         : PD7
     BS2                           : PA0
     RESET disposition             : dedicated
     RETRY pulse                   : SCK
     serial program mode           : yes
     parallel program mode         : yes
     Timeout                       : 200
     StabDelay                     : 100
     CmdexeDelay                   : 25
     SyncLoops                     : 32
     ByteDelay                     : 0
     PollIndex                     : 3
     PollValue                     : 0x53
     Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : butterfly
     Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader
```

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Found programmer: Id = "F"; type = @
    Software Version = �.u; Hardware Version = �. 
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't
a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: leave prog mode
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader

avrdude done.  Thank you.

---

I've setup the Programming interface a as a Leonardo Board. AVR ISP.

For some reason It seems as if and it might be me that the usb does not reset? and go into programming mode.

Please Help

Comment: I am not familiar with that programming environment, but to enter the bootloader on those boards you have to open the serial port at 1200 baud then close it again. Normally the Arduino IDE does that for you. Does this system? Possibly not.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Eclipse Sloeber plugin for Arduino. For serial upload over USB using bootloader choose programmer `Default`. All other programmers are for flashing over ICSP.

[image]

Comment: Okay I have installed version 2018-09 (4.9). The Toolset loaded is Arduino C++ Tools 9.5.3.201809121146. It was loaded with the help of the Yatta Plug-in interface. Under the Board  Configuration I Do not have the option to Select DEFAULT

Comment: So you don't use Sloeber Arduino Eclipse plugin

Comment: Just Re-installed  my Eclipse and found Mutiple Issues.The Path was to long under windows and this caused Sloeber not to install. I moved it and all seems to be fine now. Thanks

Comment: @MarthinusVenter, now I don't know. did my answer help or the problem was something else?